# Two delayed jobs with same Timestamp.

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

In Rails application if 2 or more **delayed jobs** are scheduled at the same run_at time eg: 24/1/2013 12:05:49 (exactly same timestamp).

Then will only one of them will execute or both will execute irrespective of same run_at timestamp.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect that both will run. If you have multiple workers running, they might well run at the same time. Otherwise, the one which is created first will run first, and the other afterward.

Comment: I figured out. The one which is created first will run first because  queue implements First In First Out.